# Confused about pip dependency package version resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

On two separate computers running Windows 11, I am trying to install the `tflite-support` package (PyPI link: https://pypi.org/project/tflite-support/)

Computer A is running Python 3.8.10 and computer B is running Python 3.10.11.

I install tflite-support using the following code:

```
python -m venv TestEnv
TestEnv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install tflite-support
```

On Computer A, tflite-support installed version is `0.4.3`.

On Computer B, tflite-support installed version is `0.1.0a1`, surprisingly.

I have two questions:

- why is the installed version 0.1.0a1 (not 0.4.3) on computer B?
- looking on PyPI, the latest version of tflite-support indeed is 0.4.4 (from July 2023). Why is the installed version 0.4.3 (not 0.4.4) on computer A?

Comment: Because `0.1.0a1` is the last version that doesn't require compiled native code, and there is no py11 windows build uploaded. You will need to compile the sourcecode or ask the maintainers to upload a compiled version. And for py38, the latest version with a compiled release for windows is 0.4.3

Comment: @MegaIng many thanks for your insight. May I ask you how you obtained this information?

Comment: Got it - I can enter the files section in PyPI and look at the available wheel files. Thanks again.